# Android Unsatisfied Link using gradle experimental v0.6.0-beta6

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to create a simple project to test the NDK in which a jnilib uses a prebuilt .so library but I keep getting an UnsatisfiedLink error:

With emulator:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "~/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloAndroidJni/app/src/main/jni/libs/dynamic/x86/libadd.so" not found
```

With actual device:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:  1675 could not load needed library '~/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloAndroidJni/app/src/main/jni/libs/dynamic/armeabi/libadd.so' for 'libhello-android-jni.so' (load_library[1093]: Library '~/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloAndroidJni/app/src/main/jni/libs/dynamic/armeabi/libadd.so' not found)
```

The .so library has a single function "add" which adds 2 numbers. I compiled it with the NDK standalone toolchain for different ABI ([doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)):

```
add.c
#include "add.h"

int add(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

My jni (.c file):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "add.h"


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_tomas_helloandroidjni_MainActivity_addNumbersJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                                  jint n1, jint n2) {

    return add(n1, n2);
}
```

My files structure looks like this:

[image: Files structure]

And my gradle file (as defined in the [experimental gradle guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies)):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            libadd{
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/prebuilts/include"
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/libs/dynamic/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libadd.so")

                }
            }
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"


        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "libadd" linkage "shared"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "hello-android-jni"
            debuggable = true
        }

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.tomas.helloandroidjni"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-android.txt"))

            }
        }

        productFlavors {
            create ("x86"){
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
            }

            create("arm"){
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            }

            create("arm7"){
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
            create ("fat"){

            }
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

I'm not sure where to look at, as I keep getting this error... Maybe I need to add a flag or something?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT 1.**

I tried with static libraries and they work fine. As a consequence (of adding the static libs) I changed the folders' structure slightly (modifying the gradle file accordingly).

I'm working on both:

1. Actual device: **Samsung GT-I8190L Android 4.1.2, API 16 -  ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)**
2. Emulator: **Nexus 4 API 23 - x86**

**EDIT 2.**

To compile the libraries I'm doing it with the [NDK Standalone Toolchain](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html):

1. Actual device (ARMv7): *SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm* and  *CC="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8 --sysroot=$SYSROOT"*
2. Emulator (x86): *SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-x86* and *CC="/Users/Tomas/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc-4.8 --sysroot=$SYSROOT"*

Comment: what you're doing should definitely work. The linking done by the plugin is somehow wrong. What happens if you call System.loadLibrary("add"); before loading hello-android-jni ? Did you try other versions of the plugin (0.7.0-alpha1..) ?

Comment: Just to sanity check - libadd.so is also present under prebuilts/armeabi, right? You've shown us it exists under prebuilts/x86, but that's not what the linker is failing to find.

Comment: @bullsy Yes, there is one in the armeabi folder.

Comment: Bah, I commented without finishing my comment... I'm going to add some details I missed to my question.
@ph0b I've tried it and I get the following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tomas.helloandroidjni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tomas.helloandroidjni-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.tomas.helloandroidjni-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libadd.so"`. 
I haven't tried other versions, I'll check it.
Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>This may not be the way these native dependencies were expected to work, but</s> *(update: this is implicitly written in the **doc**!)*  even with plugin 0.7.0, gradle does not copy **libadd.so** to the APK. There is a workaround, though; add to **build.gradle** the enchantment:

```
model {
    android.sources.main {
        jniLibs.source.srcDir 'src/main/jni/libs/dynamic'
    }
}
```

Still, I recommend to move **libs/dynamic** folder out of the **jni** sources folder.

Comment: Didn't work, but just to make sure, I have in build.gradle:
`android.sources.main.jni.dependencies { library "libadd" linkage "shared" }` and `android.sources.main.jniLibs.source { srcDir 'src/main/jni/libs/dynamic' } `
A new jniLibs folder was created with **libadd.so** for the different platforms I'm using. Where would you recommend me moving the libs folder? Thanks!

Also, where in the doc does it say that they are not copied? (could you provide the link please :)? )

Comment: Yes, you will see all the ABI variants under **jniLibs** in "Android" view of your project. These files are packaged for me on Mac. I would simply put **libs** to **src/main**. The doc says *When dependency is added to "jniLibs" the native library will be package into the application/library*. From this I can conclude that it will not be packaged if the dependency is not added to **jniLibs**.

Comment: The split of "." and "{" in gradle is very delicate. Please try the exact structure that I proposed, don't shift **jniLibs** outside the **{**.

Comment: I tried your exact structure but still the same error. I'm not sure where to put that though... If you see my gradle.build I already have a _sources_ inside the android structure. I tried putting the whole structure you proposed (`model { android... }` ) outside the model structure I had, then only with `android.sources...` inside of my model structure and finally the jniLibs inside the sources I already had.

Maybe I'm missing where to put that exactly and if I should get rid of other things I had before for it to work?

Comment: Do you see the libraries in the **jniLibs** "folder" in *Android* view of your project? This is to me the main trick. Now, if you "Build APK" and check its contents (with e.g. `unzip -l`, do you see **libadd.so** packaged?

Comment: Yes, I do see the libraries in the jniLibs. When I build the apk and unzip it you can see the libadd.so under the "lib" folder :)! But it's still throwing the error... :/

Comment: Oh, that's a whole different matter!! So, please correct me if I am wrong, we fixed the packaging: before, **libadd.so** was not packaged into the APK, now it is. Now, following **ph0b**'s suggestion, what do you see in log when you `System.loadLibrary("add")`?

Comment: Still the same error... But is the issue that the library is not being loaded to the apk? I mean, the error is saying that it can't find the library in my computer (the path being ~/AndroidStudioProjects/... ) even when I launch it in the mobile (not the emulator). Could it be that they are not properly compiled or something? (I included the info about the tools I'm using to compile the libraries)

Comment: Please answer if `System.loadLibrary("add")` fails on your device

Comment: It worked! I'll try a bit more with other libraries, recreating this steps and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it works! I'll edit your answer a bit to show all the things I have with a bit more detail. Thank you !

Comment: Your final fix was to call explicitly `System.loadLibrary("add")`, wasn't it?

Comment: Yep, along with the jniLib source thing. But it only worked with the actual device, not in emulator